# How do I target a Jumbotron element in a media query?

Tags: html, css, media-queries

Im having trouble with changing the font size of my H1 that's inside of my jumbotron, using a media query in my css file.

This is my jumbotron code:

```
<div class="jumbotron jumbotron-bike">
  <h1>Get Going</h1>
  <p>Jumpstart your startup with some crowdsourced
    seed money, or support one of our 300,000,000+
    creators and get rewards.</p>
    <a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg"href="#">Jump In</a>
</div>
```

And this is my CSS:

```
    .jumbotron h1{
  font-family: Monoton;
  font-size: 7.1rem;
}

@media only screen and (max-width:480px){
  .jumbotron h1{
    font-size: 5.7rem;
  }
}
```

When I run the website, the font size of the H1 isn't affected when I resize the page. I tested the media query with changing the body's background color and it worked so Im thinking it's something to do with the fact that the  is nested inside of a jumbotron. Im quite new to web dev so it could be something simple but I can't seem to find any answers on the web.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be working as expected. 
Check the jsfiddle below.
I changed the font-size to be much smaller on resize to easier see the change at the media query.

HTML

```
<div class="jumbotron jumbotron-bike">
  <h1>Get Going</h1>
  <p>Jumpstart your startup with some crowdsourced
    seed money, or support one of our 300,000,000+
    creators and get rewards.</p>
    <a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg"href="#">Jump In</a>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.jumbotron h1{
  font-family: Monoton;
  font-size: 7.1rem;
}

@media only screen and (max-width:480px){
  .jumbotron h1{
    font-size: 2.7rem;
  }
}
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qnfsv7go/)